# Excel VBA - How to make ActiveX radio buttons for a row only?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am new to VBA. I wanted to include ActiveX radio buttons for my data for the user to select.

[ActiveX Radio buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvlih.png)

I am not able to select the sport option and the the age range option. Only one of them gets selected. How do I overcome this?

Comment: Try to assign same group name in the properties of the respective Radio Buttons. Assign Group name 1 to both treated for Sport and 2 for Age group and check again. By default it shall be the same sheet name so all 4 are treated under one group.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have not considered the basics.

*Radio Button control can be used to select one of the many choices or options.*

Since for Sport you have two options 1. Name 2. Age.

So in this case you need to utilize the Check Box controls, *because Check Box control can be used to select as many as options.*

check the Screen Shot below,,

[image]

Purposely I've placed both Check Box & Radio Button controls in the Group control, otherwise it can be used out of the Group control also.

**Hope this solution will help you to fix the issue.**